# Jsoup parse iso-8859-1 file

Tags: java, encoding, jsoup, iso-8859-1

I've been looking online and trying to understand. I am parsing some html files that are encoded in iso-8859-1. Once parsed I want all the output to be in the standard java encoding (utf-something)

Here is how I do this:

```
currentDocument = Jsoup.parse(new File("thing.htm", "ISO-8859-1");
Element elt = currentDocument.getElementById("bim");
String title = elt.select("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6").first().text();
System.out.println(title);
```

The string in the file is:

```
G18&nbsp;Legemiddeløkonomi &#x2013; pasientens venn eller fiende
```

The output is:

```
G18?Legemiddel?konomi ? pasientens venn eller fiende
```

I guess I'm doing something wrong somewhere as I know this is possible with Jsoup I just don't really know what it is. Btw I'm on MacOSX.
Can somebody help me?

Thx

Comment: There is a `<meta charset="iso-8859-1">` in all my files so I've also tried with `Jsoup.parse(new File("thing.htm"), null);` it recognizes the ISO (according to this `currentDocument.outputSettings().charset().name()` method). But I still have so same problem of character encoding...

Comment: Try `.html()` instead of `.text()`.  But that'll cause the surrounding tags to be emitted.

Comment: It is likely that you have wrong encoding for `System.out`. Does `System.out.println("\u00f8")` print `ø` in the same circumstances?

Comment: Ok so in fact I use Lucene with these docs and when I open the documents with Luke they are well encoded. However, two things `&nbsp;`is transformed into `&#160;` is it possible to get rid of all html entities? 
I have tried to write it to a file instead of System.out and I don't get the right encoding either. Do you know how I can write or use System.out with the right encoding? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after investigating further and thanks to @Esailija I found that my console wasn't outputing in UTF-8 which was solved by:

```
PrintStream stdout = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8"); 
System.setOut(stdout);
```

I also used: `currentDocument.outputSettings().charset("UTF-8");` but I am not sure this is useful.